# Filter out powershell search based on characters

Tags: powershell

How can i filter out characters in powershell search after users in AD?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Char-eq "E"} -SearchBase "DC=Test, DC=local"
```

Comment: Have a look at these examples: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell-get-aduser-filter.htm

Comment: What do you mean "filter out characters"?  Characters in what property of the user account?  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific but I´ll just try to explain the filter parameter in general. First a bit of documentation:

> **Filter**
>
> Specifies a query string that retrieves Active Directory objects. This
>   string uses the PowerShell Expression Language syntax. The PowerShell
>   Expression Language syntax provides rich type-conversion support for
>   value types received by the Filter parameter. The syntax uses an
>   in-order representation, which means that the operator is placed
>   between the operand and the value. For more information about the
>   Filter parameter, see [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In practice it works like this:

Get all users:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter *
```

Get all users whose surname is "Smith"

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {sn -eq "Smith"}
```

Get all users who have an e-mail address and a phone number

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(mail -like "*") -and (telephonenumber -like "*")}
```

Get all users whose firstname starts with an E

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {givenname -like "E*"}
```

The supported operators are:

**FilterOperators:** "-eq" | "-le" | "-ge" | "-ne" | "-lt" | "-gt"| "-approx" | "-bor" | "-band" | "-recursivematch" | "-like" | "-notlike"

**JoinOperators** "-and" | "-or"

**NotOperators** "-not"

Hope that helps, here is a link to the full Documentation: [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)